# Spring boot kafka hello world app fails to start with "Failed to bind properties under...to..."

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I was trying basic spring boot kafka application using [this](https://dzone.com/articles/magic-of-kafka-with-spring-boot) tutorial.

My project hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

**SpringBootKafkaApplication.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootKafkaApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootKafkaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**KafkaController.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.temp.kafka_springboot_pocs.services.Producer;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/kafka")
public class KafkaController {

    private final Producer producer;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaController(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/publish")
    public void sendMessageToKafkaTopic(@RequestParam("message") String message) {
        this.producer.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Consumer {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "kafka_poc_3", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consume(String message) {
        logger.info(String.format("$$ -> Consumed Message -> %s", message));
    }
}
```

**Producer.java**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Producer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);
    private static final String TOPIC = "kafka_poc_3";

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        logger.info(String.format("$$ -> Producing message --> %s",message));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, message);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092

spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=group-1
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserialize

spring.kafka.producer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserialize
```

Spring boot application is failing to start with following error description:

Description:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer' to java.lang.Class<?>:

    Property: spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer
    Value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserialize
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:12:42
    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Class<?>]
```

What I am missing here?

**PS:** I have not worked for long in spring and spring boot. So will love someone giving me good direction / link with example or exact answer.

Comment: i think you need to add a message converter in your configuration or change you string message to a byte array

Comment: Maybe you are just missing a 'r' after `StringDeserialize`.

Comment: yikes..that was indeed the mistake!!! 

Answer (score 1):

Try with these properties:

```
#######KAFKA PRODUCER SETTING################
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer


#######KAFKA CONSUMER SETTING################
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using application.properties you can use application.yml file. It worked for me.

```
kafka:
producer:
bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431028/spring-boot-kafka-hello-world-app-fails-to-start-with-failed-to-bind-properties#comment103202733_58431028), this issue was caused by a typo in the property value.  It should have been `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer`, not `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserialize`.